# Android Warning: com.bbn.openmap.MapBean: can't find referenced class java.awt.geom.Point2D

Tags: android, openmap

I am using the openmap library to extract the esri records from shapefile and it is working fine. But when i am building a signed apk using proguard rules, the build execution is failing with a lot of warnings , below are some of the warning that build executions returned:

1. Warning: com.bbn.openmap.dataAccess.shape.MetaDbfTableModel: can't find 
   referenced class javax.swing.JFrame
2. Warning: com.bbn.openmap.MapBean: can't find referenced class java.awt.Color
3. Warning: com.bbn.openmap.MapBean: can't find referenced class java.awt.event.ContainerEvent

every class of com.bbn.openmap package returning warnings

If anyone have any solution please let me know

Answer (score 0):

java.awt and javax.swing are NOT part of Android!

You can't use classes from those libraries.

Comment: then what is the alternate of that, how can i bypass the warnings